# Benefits of Initialization lists

Tags: c++, initialization-list

Of what I know of benefits of using initialization list is that they provide efficiency when initializing class members which are not build-in. For example,

`Fred::Fred() : x_(whatever) { }`

is preferable to,

`Fred::Fred() { x_ = whatever; }`

if x is an object of a custom class. Other than that, this style is used even with built-in types for the sake of consistency.

The most common benefit of doing this is improved performance. If the expression whatever is the same type as member variable x_, the result of the whatever expression is constructed directly inside x_ — the compiler does not make a separate copy of the object.

With the other style, the expression whatever causes a separate, temporary object to be created, and this temporary object is passed into the x_ object's assignment operator. Then that temporary object is destructed at the ;. That's inefficient.

Question
Is there any efficiency gain in the following example with using initialization list.
I think there is no gain. The first version calls string's copy constructor and the other calls string's assignment operator (there isn't any temporary thats created). It that correct?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(string n):name(n) { }
private:
    string name;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(string n)
    {
        name=n;
    }
private:
    string name;
};
```

Comment: The other benefit of initialization lists (if you want to a call it a benefit) is that they're the only way to initialize certain things - base classes using a non-default ctor, const members and reference members.

Comment: Also, if you are worried about performance, I would rather used a 'const&' to pass the argument, instead of copying.

Comment: How can you have `Fred::Fred() : x_(whatever)`? Fred takes no arguments.

Comment: it is very easy to see in visual studio 2017 professional edition 'memory view' the memory addresses looks different and thus falsify all wrong assumptions here. In fact, I came to understand that the true purpose of class initialization list is for the `const` and not about speed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The second version is calling string's default ctor and then string's copy-assignment operator -- there could definitely be (minor) efficiency losses compared to the first one, which directly calls c's copy-ctor (e.g., depending on string's implementation, there might be useless allocation-then-release of some tiny structure).  Why not just always use the right way?-)

Comment: True. You should also mention that sometimes, "the right way" is the *only* option you have. If you need to initialize a reference or a const type, or something which doesn't have an assignment operator, you don't have much choice in the matter

Comment: @jalf true, but not directly applicable to the code the OP gives (only to variants using e.g. `string&` members instead of `string` ones).

Comment: Don't you mean it's calling `string`'s copy constructor, and then its assignment operator?

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. The primary purpose for class initialization list is mainly for the `const` and wither it is about speed is only accidental.

Answer (score 21):

I think the only way to initialize const data members is in the initialization list

Eg. in the header:

```
class C
{
    C();
private:
    const int x;
    int y;
}
```

And the in the cpp file:

```
C::C() :
    x( 10 ),
    y( 10 )
{
    x = 20; // fails
    y = 20;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The `const` usage here clearly and without doubt the primary unambiguous crystal clear usage that only works when inside a `class initialization list`.

Answer (score 14):

Remember that there is a distinct difference between a copy constructor and an assignment operator:

- the copy ctor *constructs* a new object using some other instance as a place to get initialization information from.
- the assignment operator modifies an already existing object that has already been fully constructed (even if it's only by using a default constructor)

So in your second example, some work has already been done to create `name` by the time that

```
 name=n;
```

is reached.

However, it's quite possible (especially in this simple example) that the work done is vanishingly small (probably just zeroing out some data members in the `string` object) and that the work is optimized away altogether in an optimized build.  but it's still considered good form to use initializer lists whenever possible.

Comment: Very well said.  While this is basic, this is something that is very easy to overlook/forget for someone like myself who learned on C and assembly.

Answer (score 14):

It's a great way to initialize members that :

- are const
- don't have a default constructor (it's private)

Answer (score 2):

We can also perform the [constructor delegation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Fdelegating_ctors.html) via the initialization list.