# Why is the copy-constructor argument const?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
 Vector(const Vector& other) // Copy constructor 
 {
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
```

Why is the argument a const?

Comment: That should be `Vector(const Vector& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}` Read about initialization lists and why they're good to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/

Comment: const-correctness is probably a term you want to look up

Comment: Although it's const 99% of the time, there is a counter-example; see std::auto_ptr.

Comment: Of course `auto_ptr` is deprecated because even the experts at the standards committee didn't manage to get it completely right. Therefore I'd say if you find a non-const argument to a copy constructor, you can be fairly sure the code is broken.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You've gotten answers that mention ensuring that the ctor can't change what's being copied -- and they're right, putting the const there does have that effect.

More important, however, is that a temporary object cannot bind to a non-const reference. The copy ctor must take a reference to a const object to be able to make copies of temporary objects.

Comment: And not only temporary objects - it also allows the copy constructor to be used on named objects that happen to be marked const.

Comment: This is super confusing. Can you tell me the difference between "const Vector& other" and "Vector const &other"?

Comment: @HoyCheung: There is no difference between those.

Comment: @HoyCheung The "readable" way to put the `const` specifier is after the type you want to make `const`. For example: `int cont * cont` to create a constant pointer to constant integer (an inverse reading of the declarator matches the type you are defining), but the first `const` (if any) can be also placed before (`const int * const`), I think for some kind of compatibility with primitive versions of C, or simply for tradition.

Answer (score 21):

Because you are not going to modify the argument `other` inside the copy ctor as it is const.

When you did `x = other.x` it essentially means `this->x  = other.x`. So you are modifying only `this` object just by copying the values from `other` variable. Since the `other` variable is read-only here, it is passed as a const-ref.

Comment: It's considered "good defensive programming" by (a) telling the caller that they don't have to worry about changes to the argument being passed in and (b) telling the implementor that they are not allowed to change the argument.

Comment: It's also necessary because you want to be able to bind rvalues to the ctor's argument: `X x = f();`. This isn't possible with non-const references.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional copy-ctor and friends take a `const&` parameter for reasons specified above. However, you should also look up [move-semantics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm) and [r-value references](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1690.html) (to be part of C++0x, if all goes well) to see why and when you will use copy-ctors without a `const&` parameter. Another place to look at is the implementation of smart pointers such as [`auto_ptr`](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm) (which have transfer of ownership semantics) where non-const parameters are useful.

Answer (score 1):

In order to *not* be able to change `other` (by accident)?

Answer (score 1):

when we try to  copy one object into another using copy constructor,we need to maintain the original copy of original object (which we are copying) so while passing object we make it constant and we pass it as a by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a copy constructor is that you are copying the contents of the `other` object into the `this` object. The const is there to ensure that you don't modify the `other` object.

Answer (score 0):

Its not specific to copy constructor. In any function if you are not going to modify the internal state of the object then object will be passed as `const`.

```
Vector(const Vector& other) 
{
     //Since other is const, only public data member and public methods which are `const` can be accessed.
}
```

Comment: Since `Vector` is a `Vector`, can't you can access private members of `other`?.  If you replaced the `Vector` argument with `OtherClass`, you can't access private members.

Comment: @jamuraa: You can access them, but you are not allowed to modify them. To attempt to is a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

It can also come handy if you want to copy an object you only have a const reference to for example

```
...
const Vector& getPosition();
...

Vector* v = new Vector(getPosition());
```

If it wasn't for `Vector(const Vector& other)` that example would create a syntax error.