# Advantages of using initializer list?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of Initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists)

I was wondering if there was an advantage to initializing members with the initializer list over putting these in the constructor. Certain things have to use the initialize list but for the majority of things that don't, is there a difference? I prefer the latter because when I have multiple constructors, I prefer simply calling construct() to promote code reuse.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't use the initializer list, the member or base class gets default constructed before the opening curly brace.

So, your calls to set it later will add an `operator=()` call.

If you use the initializer list, the member or base class has the proper constructor called.

Depending on your classes, this might be required or faster.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample example.

Answer (score 12):

For primitives, there is no difference between using initializer lists or constructing them via assignment.

For other types, initializer lists might afford you performance improvements when constructing objects.

Do note that the order of initializing (in initializer lists) depends on the order of declaration in the class. If the declarations are out of order and you need to construct data that depends on something else already being initialized before hand, that is an exception to the 'use initialization lists when possible rule'.

More info: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6

Comment: Excellent answer.  A point I'd like to add... it might make sense (based on the number of constructors you have) to put the portion of the constructor that assigns values to primatives in a private Init() function.  This prevent code duplication in the initializer lists.

Comment: @birryree nice point about the sequence of arguments could you please elaborate on the advantages of using initializer list in case of non-primitives type.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what everyone else has mentioned, it allows disambiguation of shadow variable, so where would have to write `this->var = var` you can instead do `myclass(int var) : var(var)`. Of course some people might find this very confusing/hard to read if you have a big constructor

Answer (score 3):

Also, never perform unmanaged resource acquisition in initializer lists. In other words, either use "resource acquisition is initialization" (thereby avoiding unmanaged resources entirely) or else perform the resource acquisition in the constructor body.

And warning #2
Perform every resource allocation (e.g., new) in its own code statement which immediately gives the new resource to a manager object (e.g., auto_ptr).

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm

Answer (score 2):

other than being forced to use an initializer list for constants and references, It also useful because with it you avoid default constructing member objects before the constructor is entered and then immediately assigning it, which can be inefficient if the member objects are expensive to construct