# Syntax "Foo(int v) : val_(v) {}"?

Tags: c++, syntax

I am going through some code and I am having dificulty in comprehending the syntax:

```
  struct Foo {

  int val_;

  Foo(int v) : val_(v) {}  //--->THIS LINE

  };
```

The colon `:` seems like a member access operator.

Can I get a clear explanation the above line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its initializing `val_` to `v`.

See: [Constructor Initialization Lists](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/)

Comment: Foo(**int v**) or foo() does it makes any differnce.Is parameter **int v** required for this initialization.if not why is that parameter there

Comment: @munish Whatever you are passing into the constructor as the parameter v is the value to which `val_` is initialized, so yes, you do need the parameter for the constructor.

Comment: Though you can use initializer lists with no constructor parameters.  For example, `Foo() : val_(5) {}` would cause every default-constructed `Foo` to have 5 as the initial value of member `val_`.

Answer (score 1):

Structures in C++ can have constructors just like classes do.  This is initializing the public variable `val_` to `v` just as if you had `val_ = v;` in the constructor body.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists) for their benefits in terms of efficiency.