# c++ self in initialisation list

Tags: c++, initialization-list

i have this code snippet

```
class Osoba{
         Osoba(char* imie,int wiek){                         
                     this->imie=new char[strlen(imie)+1];
                     strcpy(this->imie,imie);
                     this->wiek=wiek;
                     cout<<"Utworzono Osobe "<<this->imie<<endl;
         }
         Osoba(Osoba& x){
                 Osoba(x.imie,x.wiek);
         }
[...]
```

and when i call the copy constructor it doesnt work (creates and destroyes object).

Edit:
if i use

```
         Osoba(Osoba& x): Osoba(x.imie,x.wiek){
```

i get `type 'class Osoba' is not a direct base of 'Osoba'`

how is this done ?

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char *` to represent strings in C++. It makes things much simpler. Also, your title suggests something about initialization lists, but you are not using any on the code you show.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists)

Comment: @c0wb0y i know its just for educational purposes -> why i use char* (dynamic memory alloc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a constructor except for creating another different object.

If you need to have some code in common between constructors you can place it in a separate method and call that method. Note that in the constructor you can call methods of the object but `virtual` methods are not going to dispatch do derived classes.

In other words if you have

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void doit() { ... }
    Foo() {
        doit();
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    virtual void doit() { ... }
};
```

during the constructor of `Bar` the implementation of `doit` called will be the one defined in `Foo` because during the constructor of the base part of the derived object, the object is only a "base" object. Only at the **end of the constructor** it becomes a "derived" object right before executing any eventually present code in the "derived" constructor.

Be careful that other object oriented languages use a different approach...

For an explanation of what happens exactly in C++ [see this article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

If you like instead a legalese description this is what is stated in the C++ standard at 12.7.4:

> Member functions, including virtual
>   functions (10.3), can be called during
>   construction or destruction (12.6.2).
>   When a virtual function is called
>   directly or indirectly from a
>   constructor (including from the
>   mem-initializer for a data member) or
>   from a destructor, and the object to
>   which the call applies is the object
>   under construction or destruction, the
>   function called is the one defined in
>   the constructor or destructor’s own
>   class or in one of its bases, but not
>   a function overriding it in a class
>   derived from the constructor or
>   destructor’s class, or overriding it
>   in one of the other base classes of
>   the most derived object (1.8). If the
>   virtual function call uses an explicit
>   class member access (5.2.5) and the
>   object-expression refers to the object
>   under construction or destruction but
>   its type is neither the constructor or
>   destructor’s own class or one of its
>   bases, the result of the call is
>   undefined.

Comment: i will accept this because is most helpful :) quick and nasty hacks is what i like.

Comment: I think *"during the constructor of Bar the implementation of doit called will be the one defined in Foo"* is not entirely true. Does the  Standard say that? Is it not unspecified/undefined?

Comment: @Nawaz: I can't find it in the standard but pdf searching sucks (and searching dead tree versions is even harder ;-) ). I added anyway a link to an explanation of the exact dynamic. I clearly remember reading about this from an authoritative source when I was studying C++ (but it was many years ago so I don't remember exactly what was the source... probably TCPPPL).

Answer (score 10):

You can't call constructors like that. Well you can, but what happens is a nameless temporary  object gets created. Write your copy constructor without reference to the other constructor. Also, if you use std::string instead of char *, you won't need a copy constructor. If you persist in using char  *, you will also need a destructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: are u 100% sure u cant re-use other constructors ?, and yes i have a destructor i know about string :)

Comment: @noob You can't re-use other constructors, but you can sometimes factor out the code into a non-constructor private member function.

Comment: @noob: and don't forget to define the copy constructor properly: Osoba(**const** Osoba& x)

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the members of `Osoba`, the same way as you are doing in the other constructor.

You can only reuse constructors (with other syntax) in C++2011.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the constructor is not just any method, you can't just use at as a mutator method.

that said,
Am I right in thinking that your class had two fields, imie and wiek?

just do the init code again, this time with x.imie and x.wiek as input