# C++ initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class construction with initial values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207884/class-construction-with-initial-values)

While I was looking at c++ example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern I noticed something I haven't seen before:

```
C() : i(new A()) { }
```

My question is: How is this line of code any different from:

```
C() {
    i = new A();
}
```

What does `:` after constructor do? What does the brackets around `new A()` do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class construction with initial values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207884/class-construction-with-initial-values) and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists

Comment: I didn't know what it's called so I didn't know what to search for, sorry for duplicate, I'll read topics you linked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its called [initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6). It is used to initialize the data members of a class.

```
C() {
    i = new A(); // i is not initialized here, here assignment is taking place.
}
```

Comment: There is also a multitude of reasons to do those in the same order as their declarations.

Comment: Also, before C++11, const members could only be initialized with member initializer syntax.

Comment: @EdHeal Because the sequence of initialization of class variables are just the sequence of declaring them.

Comment: @xis - Say, for example, one is an array and the other is the size of the array. Things get undefined.