# Problem with constructors and including headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, compiler-errors, header-files

I guess this can be a conceptual problem, but I couldn't find anything to solve it. I'm new to C++, and I'm having troubles with the includes (i'm working in **Visual Studio 2017** on **Windows 10**). I've created these classes:

- **Shader**
- **Material**
- **Mesh**

Each one of them with their .h and .cpp files respectively. The .h of each one of them looks like this:

**Shader.h**

```
#pragma once
class Shader
{
public:
    //Default constructor
private:
    //Some stuff
}
```

**Material.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Shader.h"

class Material
{
public:
    Material(Shader s);
private:
    //Some stuff
}
```

**Mesh.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Material.h"

class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh(Material m);
private:
    //Some stuff
}
```

The problem appears in Mesh.cpp, when I write this:

**Mesh.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(Material mat)
{

}
```

If I write that, Visual Studio gives me this error (marking in red the first bracket of the constructor):

> No default constructor exists for class "Material"

Why is it assuming that I'm defining Material class constructor only by including Material.h in the header of Mesh class? Another problem appears if I just remove the constructor and try to create an object of type Mesh in, for example, Main.cpp. 
If I do this (letting Mesh with default constructor):

```
Mesh m = Mesh();
```

The compiler says:

> The default constructor of Mesh::Mesh cannot be referenced - - it is a
>   deleted function

I don't know what to do or what to search for. Hope I gave you the necessary information to help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219242/default-constructor-missing-but-im-not-calling-it

Comment: As soon you do this `Mesh(Material m);` the default constructor is deleted by the compiler automatically. Copy constructors and assignment operators are strill generated as usual.

Comment: `Mesh() = default;` - *iff* the compiler generated default constructor works for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll try them out when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’ve left something out of your sample code. The class `Mesh` has a data member of type `Material`, doesn’t it? `Material` doesn’t have a default constructor, so every constructor for `Mesh` has to explicitly initialize the `Material` member.

```
Mesh::Mesh(Material mat)
{ // no initializer for Material data member
)
```

Add an initializer list. Assuming the data member is named `m`, the constructor should look like this:

```
Mesh::Mesh(Material mat)
: m(mat) // initializes m
{
}
```

Comment: It does have a member variable of type Material, yes. So, if the constructor is only used to pass the 'Material' object, I'd have to add your code and leave the body empty?