# Both Integer and function in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
  // single parameter constructor, can be used as an implicit conversion
  Foo (int foo) : m_foo (foo) 
  {
  }

  int GetFoo () { return m_foo; }

private:
  int m_foo;
};
```

m_foo is an integer as defined in private section,   but what's m_foo(foo)?   that looks like a function.

is m_foo both an integer and a function? How does that work?

And Foo(int foo) contructor is extending the m_foo function.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists

Comment: It's like doing `int x(42);` in a local context, but instead doing it in an initialization list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Answer (score 5):

```
Foo (int foo) : m_foo (foo)
```

This is an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It initialises `m_foo` to have the value `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing a integer variable using initializer list. Essentially before you enter the body of the constructor `m_foo` is assinged to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an intializer.  It sets the value of the `m_foo` item by calling it's copy-constructor (instead of creating a temporary object and then calling the copy-constructor if you were to set it in the constructor like `m_foo = foo`).

Answer (score -1):

<sup>I'm not sure that basic questions about C++ have their place here, however:</sup>

```
Foo (int foo) : m_foo (foo)
```

means: define a constructor, and initialize the member variable `m_foo` with the `foo` formal argument.