# structure defined inside of class

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in c++, consider the following snippet:

```
class myClass
{
  ...
  struct EntryKeyBase
  {
     void setOperation(OpType oper)
     {
        operation = oper;
     }
     OpType getOperation() const
     {
        return operation;
     }
     virtual void serialize(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
     protected:
        OpType operation;
    };

  struct ProtoEntryKey: EntryKeyBase
  {
     // some methods here

     ProtoEntryKey(uint8_t l4proto) : proto(l4proto)  // ???
     {
        operation = Inserted;
     }

     protected:
        uint8_t proto;
  };

  // here more structs defined...


  public:
    ...

};
```

What does the line marked ??? do? I understand that we declare structure inheriting from EntryKeyBase, but whatever follows ':' I don't understand, what does this syntax really mean?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a constructor. Please find a good C++ text book; this is one of the most fundamental concepts of the language and well learnable without asking a question here.

Comment: Also, it is usually a bad idea to have identifiers like `l4` where the lower case L can be easily confused with a number one.

Comment: Also note that this has absolutely nothing to do with the structure being nested.

Answer (score 3):

It is an *initialization list*. it assigns value of **l4proto** to **proto** variable in struct *ProtoEntryKey*.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple constructor. If you write `: somefield(somevalue)` after constructor it will set value of `somefileld` to `somevalue`.

In your example it will set value of `proto` to `l4proto` (constructor argument).

Comment: It is not simple. It's also not a constructor. It's a (base/member) initializer list. Which can be a part of a constructor. Yes

Comment: So it would have the same meaning if I put `proto=l4proto` inside of the body of `ProtoEntryKey` ?

Comment: @Mark:  No.  If you put it inside the constructor, the default constructor gets called for each member, and then the copy-assignment will get called.  Putting it in an intializer-list makes it so only the copy-constructor gets called for the members in the initializer-list.

Answer (score 0):

`proto` is a unit18_t member. It makes sense to initialise it in the constructor.

The `:` indicates the initialiser list. You can initialise base classes and member here.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the constructor that sets `proto` variable to `l4proto` value.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists) link may be useful.