# Is there any difference while assigning value in ctor?

Tags: c++

While I was working in c++ I see two type of ctor definition.. Is there any difference while assigning value? Does one of them has advantages or just writing style ?

1st ctor definition:

```
class X
{
public: 
    X(int val):val_(val){}
private:
    int val_;
};
```

2nd ctor definition:

```
class X
{
public: 
    X(int val)
    {
       val_ = val;
    }
private:
    int val_;
};
```

Comment: You cannot use the second syntax to store references.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes, although you can typically not observe any difference for built-in types like `int`.

The difference is that your first snippet copy-constructs `val_` from `val`, while the second one default constructs `val_` and then assigns `val` to it. As I said above, this usually only matters for more complex types whose constructors actually do work.

A simple example which demonstrates the difference would be

```
class X
{
public: 
    X(int val):val_(val){}
private:
    const int val_;
};
```

which compiles vs.

```
class X
{
public: 
    X(int val)
    {
       val_ = val;
    }
private:
    const int val_;
};
```

which does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference. In a constructor initializer list, the member variables are constructed, while the assignments in the constructor body is assignments to already constructed variables.

For the basic types like `int` or `float` it's no actual difference though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no difference. Since your member is an `int`, the two statements have the same effect.

If your member variable was an object, the first form would be better, because it would simply call the constructor of the object class, while the second form would create an object by using the default constructor, then create another, store it into a temporary, call the destructor on the first object, copy the temporary into your member variable, call the destructor again on the second object.