# why we not use this keyword, if constructor is defined outside class?

Tags: c++, oop

while defining a constructor outside class, this keyword is not used to create variables.

```
Person::Person(int initialAge){
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        if(initialAge > 0){
            this.age = initialAge;
        }else{
            this.age =0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This does not compile. `this->age` could. Please post [mcve] and state your question. Using or not using `this` has nothing to do where any method is declared.

Comment: strictly speaking you never use the `this` keyword to "create variables". what exactly are you refering to? The question is rather unclear, because your example is not inline but still has the keyword `this`

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you define your constructor in the way you do makes no odds on whether or not you use `this`.

`this` can be used to disambiguate between a local variable or a class member.

Since there is no local variable `age` in scope, the language assumes you are referring to a class member, so `this` is superfluous, although some folk retain it for purported clarity.

In C++ you'd need to write `this->age` to access the member, or the less clear `(*this).age`.

You constructor could be written as

```
Person::Person(int initialAge) : age(std::max(0, initialAge))
{
}
```

Reference: [Benefits of Initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598967/benefits-of-initialization-lists)